# Monoid that is idempotent induces partial ordering

Tags: order-theory, monoid, idempotents

Given a commutative monoid $(M,0,\oplus)$.
Then we can define an ordering on $M$ by

$a\geq b :\Leftrightarrow \exists c: a=b\oplus c$.

The relation is then transitive and reflexive. The claim is now the following:

Assume that $M$ is idempotent, i.e. $m\oplus m = m$ for any $m\in M$.
Then the relation $\geq$ defined above is antisymmetric, i.e. if
$a\geq b$ and $b\geq a$ then $b=a$.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: where did your find this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a=b\oplus  c$, then 
$$ a\oplus b=b\oplus (b\oplus c)=(b\oplus b)\oplus a=b\oplus c=a.$$
In other words,
$$ a\ge b\implies a\oplus b=a.$$
So if $a\ge b$ **and** $b\ge a$, we have
$$a=a\oplus b=b\oplus a = b.$$